# How Do I Select A Distinct Row But Also Add An Original Column On

Tags: mysql

The following MySql;

```
SELECT DISTINCT students.id
              , students.added
              , students.email
              , students.assessment 
           FROM db.students as students
          ORDER 
             BY students.email ASC
              , students.added DESC 
              , students.id DESC 
          LIMIT 10000000
```

Is giving me

```
'1751','2020-09-23 18:03:41','a@b.com','Module 6 Assessment'
'1741','2020-09-23 18:02:30','a@b.com','Module 6 Assessment'
'1731','2020-09-23 17:59:59','a@b.com','Module 6 Assessment'
'1721','2020-09-23 17:45:41','a@b.com','Module 5 Assessment'
'1711','2020-09-23 17:23:30','a@b.com','Module 4 Assessment'
```

But I don't want the 'Module 6 Assessment' to be repeated 3 times, I only want the last (and most up to date completion of that assessment to be shown).

I can remove the students.id and students.added to 'collapse it down' which works, but then I loose the added time of that record.

How can I get the distinct AND also have the extra data added to the final set?

Comment: Group by email and assessment and take maximal id and date (or make group concatenation for these columns).

Comment: " I don't want the 'Module 6 Assessment' to be repeated 3 times"...so what do you want instead? It's not fully clear. Show an example of the exact result set you require.

Comment: I updated the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, it may be

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id, ' => ', added SEPARATOR '\n'), email, assessment 
FROM students
GROUP BY email, assessment 
ORDER BY email ASC, MAX(added) DESC
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fded0855de8229038e0ed64b17d49f65)

Comment: @Exitos Please do NOT edit someone else's answer if you are not ABSOLUTELY sure that your correction removes error or typo only - avoid to alter answer's author idea. And especially avoid to edit the query altering correct SQL code to INCORRECT (even when it is workable in your environment) one! If your final solution looks not like a code in the answer - you may add self-answer with your code which was created using obtained information, or add this code as an update into the question text.

Comment: @Exitos Set `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode and try to make your query work...